# How to test dataset iterators within jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to experiment with different functions to parse my csv and I am trying to use the tf.dataset iterators, yet I am having trouble getting this to work.  My goal with the code below is to essentially print the first parsed row.

```
import tensorflow as tf
filenames = 'my_dataset.csv'
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames).skip(1).map(lambda row: parse_csv(row, hparams))
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_row = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(next_x))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Now if I run this you will see that I get `FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized. Ensure that you have run the initializer operation for this iterator before getting the next element.` so then I proceed to uncomment the `iterator.initializer` and I get another error `ValueError: Iterator does not have an initializer.`

What changes need to be made to actually step through to see what is happening with my parse_csv call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run `sess.run(next_x)` instead of `sess.run(next_row)`.